# Setting Current Date in Android

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am using the below code to get a formatted date as 31-12-2014.

```
private Calendar mDummyDate;
mDummyDate = Calendar.getInstance();
mDummyDate.set(mDummyDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), 11, 31);
```

When i take logs, the year in `mDummyDate` is set as 1970. What could be the reason?

Comment: I'm getting the correct output with your code.

Comment: I'm running the same code and getting 1970 as year

Comment: I tried the code and get the current date correctly. Here is my output on running `System.out.println(mDummyDate.getTime());` Wed Dec 31 16:19:31 IST 2014

Comment: Could you try the same sysout and post your output?

Comment: @Sid Hmm weird. http://ideone.com/vsyYzS.

Comment: You can format the date with `SimpleDateFormat`...I'll post my code in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.. I get `31-12-2014` as output.

```
Calendar mDummyDate;
mDummyDate = Calendar.getInstance();
mDummyDate.set(mDummyDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), 11, 31);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(mDummyDate.getTime());
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Comment: using this i am getting 02-00-1970 as output

Comment: Is you computer's time set?

Comment: i just rebooted my phone and it worked. Now i am getting the correct output

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this code and it should call your systems date to pull the information

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: How are you testing the application?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
package com.xcart;

import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;    

public class GetCurrentDateTime {
   public static void main(String[] args) {    
       DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
       //get current date time with Date()
       Date date = new Date();
       //System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)); don't print it, but save it!
       String yourDate = dateFormat.format(date);   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Hope this will help you

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String currentDate = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Thanks :)